# Get back to previous version in remote repository with git

Tags: git, github

I did a commit 2 days ago by mistake in git remote repository that make a lot of errors in live website.

How can I get back to previous version before 2 days ago but in remote repository not in my local test code only?

**EDIT**

I do `git checkout master`

[image]

Comment: Those messages in your screenshot (by the way, don't use screenshots when cut-and-paste of text would suffice, as is the case here: see [ask]) tell me that you have *uncommitted work* in your local repository. Use a different clone, or a separate work tree, to fix up the remote repository you want to fix up. Or, if this *is* the remote repository, figure out why it has uncommitted work in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. git reset --hard            #reset local changes
2. git clean -fd               #remove untracked files and folders
3. git fetch                   #fetch latest
4. git checkout master         #switch to master
5. git pull                    #get latest from master
6. git checkout -b my-fix-branch     #create new branch from master
7. git revert {faulty-commit-hash}   #remove your change
8. git push -u origin my-fix-branch:my-fix-branch #push to remote
9. git checkout master         #switch again to master
10. git merge my-fix-branch    #merge fix to master
11. git push                   #push to master

Notes:

- If you get merge conflicts on step 7 you will need to fix them.
- If you don't have rights to modify master directly, after step 8 create a pull request from "my-fix-branch" to "master"